# Swift - presentCodeRedemptionSheet() is not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I want to implement in-app purchase with offer code to my app, I have setup the offer code in App Store Connect and try to display the redemption sheet for users to enter the offer code. I read some solutions to use presentCodeRedemptionSheet(). However, is not working, the sheet is not coming up. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func applyOfferCodeButtonDidPress(_ sender: Any) {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().presentCodeRedemptionSheet()
        }
}
```

I have a button, after clicked I want to display the sheet.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the keyboard tap `Return` button on the bottom-right corner, not the `Done` button on the top-right.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. The redemption sheet is not showing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).